inotifywait to convert (ffmpeg) multiple files
I want to automatize a job, i.e. the conversion of videos (taken by mobile phones) with ffmpeg on my nextcloud server. The bashscript I run manually runs fine:
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.3gp *.avi *.m4v *.mp4 *.mov *.3GP *.AVI *.M4V *.MP4 *.MOV; do
        if [ "${i: -8}" != "conv.mp4" ]; then
        echo $i
        fi
done
curdir1=$(pwd | sed "s|/mnt/red_8tb/data||")
curdir2=$(echo $curdir1 | sed 's|/[^\/]*$||')

mkdir -p originals

for i in *.3gp *.avi *.m4v *.mp4 *.mov *.3GP *.AVI *.M4V *.MP4 *.MOV; do
        if [ "${i: -8}" != "conv.mp4" ]; then
        sudo nice -19 ffmpeg -threads 1 -benchmark -i "$i"  -qscale:v 0 -movflags '+faststart +use_metadata_tags' "${i%.*}_conv.mp4"
        mv "$i" originals
        fi
done

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *
echo "$curdir2"
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/nextcloud/occ files:scan -p "$curdir2"

Since my family also uses the nextcloud, and the +faststart option is so desirable, I wrote this code to use inotifywait to enable them do the conversion themself/automatically, i.e. triggered by moving/uploading videos into a specific directory:
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -m /mnt/red_8tb/data/Beres/files/originals/WORKLIST_VIDEOS -e create -e moved_to | \
  while read directory action file; do
    if [[ "${file: -8}" != "conv.mp4" ]]; then
      if [[ "${file: -4}" == ".3gp" || "${file: -4}" == ".avi" || "${file: -4}" == ".m4v" || "${file: -4}" == ".mov" || "${file: -4}" == ".mp4" || "${file: -4}" == ".3GP" || "${file: -4}" == ".AVI" || "${file: -4}" == ".M4V" || "${file: -4}" == ".MOV" || "${file: -4}" == ".MP4" ]]; then
        echo "$directory""$file"
        sleep 5s
        sudo nice -19 ffmpeg -threads 1 -i "$directory""$file" -qscale:v 0 -movflags '+faststart +use_metadata_tags' "$directory"/test/"${file%.*}_conv.mp4"
        sudo chown -R www-data:www-data "$directory"/test/"${file%.*}_conv.mp4"
        curdir1=$(echo "$directory" | sed "s|/mnt/red_8tb/data||")
        curdir2=$(echo $curdir1 | sed 's|/[^\/]*$||')
        sudo -u www-data php /var/www/nextcloud/occ files:scan -p "$curdir2"
      fi
    fi
  done

Unfortunately, only one video gets converted when I move several. If I move another video into the directory, after (!) ffmpeg finishes, this new video also gets converted, so the script is not "stuck", yet fails to loop through multiple files. Other operations, e.g. moving the files into a directory, work as intended.
btw: I am aware of this question: Use Inotifywait to handle multiple files at the same time, but it doesn't seem to help :-(

this sounds a lot like you should instead figure out the hooks that nextcloud offers you to get informed about finished uploads. You're trying to solve the wrong end of the problem, I'd say.

the idea of running ffmpeg 1. as root 2. at very high priority and 3. with potentially malicious input is very very bad. Don't run a transcoder as root. Running it at high priority will also not make if faster, unless your CPU is busy doing other things that you are willing to interrupt. Also probably a very bad idea.

"nice -19" actually means priority is low, "--19" would be high priority... and the files are already on the server, is the idea. Running as root at the moment for testing. Thanks anyhow. Do you have an idea how to solve the problem?

yes, see my first comment. And don't run "as root for testing". If you need root to run, your software doesn't work yet.

a hook from nextcloud about the upload of a file won't help. The files are already there and I don't want to convert every file, but give people the possibility to decide for themselves which files (that have already been uploaded) to convert.

I can't see anything wrong by looking at it, might it be that the ffmpeg command is creating a temporary file in the current working directory, messing up the loop? What about the PHP script? Also note that curdir2 will end up being /Beres/files/originals/WORKLIST_VIDEOS, not sure if this is intended.

@kos: I think (...) ffmpeg is creating the output file directly, i.e. w/o a temporary file, since you can ls -l and see it grow? concerning the curdir2: thanks, at the moment, this seems weird, but is inconsequential as a nextcloud scan of a higher level includes the lower levels and I was experimenting where to put the resulting, converted videos.

@Beres I don't understand: if you want people to trigger an action from nextcloud, you very clearly would want that to appear as a UI operation within Nextcloud; not by trying to hack some RPC semantic onto a file system ? Look at it from the "very does the intent of the user flow from" point of view: the user does something with their nextcloud interface. At that point all the information is there for you to use: which files they want to convert; and it's also the point where you need to reflect success of the operation back to. So, you need to initiate the operation from within nextcloud.

And with that I mean that you need to use a mechanism that takes the list of files that the user, in nextcloud, marks as "to be converted", and puts that list into a queue. A file system directory makes for a very bad queue.

@Marcus: you are of course right, the interaction would be perfect if it could be triggered from within the nextlcoud frontend. There are already such tools (media converter app), but I can't get them to work :-( And I am not skillful enough to create such an app myself. So my idea was to tell the users (like <10 people) that "there is a directory that converts your mobile phone videos automatically". I know that this "hidden" background process is not really ideal. Thanks for your ideas!

but you're really making this more complicated to you than it needs to be that way :)

Found it :-)! The solution is to run ffmpeg with the -nostdin option, as ffmpeg "swallows" the read output. So this little change makes it work as intended:
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -m /mnt/red_8tb/data/Beres/files/originals/WORKLIST_VIDEOS -e create -e moved_to |
        while read directory action file; do
                if [[ "${file: -8}" != "conv.mp4" ]]; then
                        if [[ "${file: -4}" == ".3gp" || "${file: -4}" == ".avi" || "${file: -4}" == ".m4v" || "${file: -4}" == ".mov" || "${file: -4}" == ".mp4" || "${file: -4}" == ".3GP" || "${file: -4}" == ".AVI" || "${file: -4}" == ".M4V" || "${file: -4}" == ".MOV" || "${file: -4}" == ".MP4" ]]; then
                        echo "$directory""$file"
                        sleep 5s
                        sudo nice -19 ffmpeg -nostdin -threads 1 -i "$directory""$file" -qscale:v 0 -movflags '+faststart +use_metadata_tags' "$directory"/test/"${file%.*}_conv.mp4"
                        sudo chown -R www-data:www-data "$directory"/test/"${file%.*}_conv.mp4"
                        curdir1=$(echo "$directory" | sed "s|/mnt/red_8tb/data||")
                        curdir2=$(echo $curdir1 | sed 's|/[^\/]*$||')
                        sudo -u www-data php /var/www/nextcloud/occ files:scan -p "$curdir2"
                        fi
                fi
        done


I really do not think you want -e create, -e close would be far better which should also mean you do not need the sleep.

would -e create catch a file that was uploaded (although this is unlikely)? What is it's benefit?

It does not matter whether it was uploaded, the file system is the file system.
